# Getting Vista Folder Paths

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

Why will this not compile in Delphi 2009?

```
unit VistaFolders;

interface

uses Windows, ShellAPI, ShlObj;

type
  KNOWNFOLDERID = TGuid;

const
  FOLDERID_ProgramData: KNOWNFOLDERID =
    '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'; // downloads folder

var
  SHGetKnownFolderPathFunc: function( const rfid: KNOWNFOLDERID;
    dwFlags: DWORD; hToken: THandle; var ppszPath: PWideChar ): HResult; stdcall;
  SHGetKnownFolderIDListFunc: function( const rfid: KNOWNFOLDERID;
    dwFlags: DWORD; hToken: THandle; var ppidl: PItemIDList ): HResult; stdcall;

  function GetDownloadsFolderPath: string;

implementation

uses ActiveX;

function PathFromIDList( Pidl: ShlObj.PItemIdList ): string;
var
  Path: array[ 0..MAX_PATH ] of Char;
begin
  if SHGetPathFromIDList( Pidl, Path ) then
    Result := Path
  else
    Result := '';
end;

function GetDownloadsFolderPath: string;
var
  Path: PWideChar;
  Pidl: PItemIdList;
begin
  Result := '';
  if @SHGetKnownFolderPathFunc <> nil then
  begin
    if Succeeded( SHGetKnownFolderPathFunc( FOLDERID_ProgramData, 0, 0, Path ) ) then
      begin
        try
          Result := Path;
        finally; CoTaskMemFree( Path ); end;
        Exit;
      end;
  end
  else if @SHGetKnownFolderIDListFunc <> nil then
  begin
    if Succeeded( SHGetKnownFolderIDListFunc( FOLDERID_ProgramData, 0, 0, Pidl ) ) then
      begin
        try
          Result := PathFromIDList( Pidl );
        finally; CoTaskMemFree( Pidl ); end;
        Exit;
      end;
  end;
  if Succeeded( SHGetFolderLocation( 0, CSIDL_PROFILE, 0, 0, Pidl ) ) then
    try
      Result := PathFromIDList( Pidl ) + '\Downloads';
    finally; CoTaskMemFree( Pidl ); end;
end;

procedure InitVistaFunctions;
var
  hShell32: THandle;
begin
  hShell32 := GetModuleHandle( 'SHELL32' );
  @SHGetKnownFolderPathFunc := Windows.GetProcAddress( Shell32, 'SHGetKnownFolderPath' );
  @SHGetKnownFolderIDListFunc := Windows.GetProcAddress( Shell32, 'SHGetKnownFolderIDList' );
end;

initialization
  InitVistaFunctions;

end.
```

Comment: The compiler usually TELLS you why something won't compile. Don't make everyone else guess. Include the compiler's error message and location when you ask what the problem is.

Comment: @Bill Miller: if mghie's answer was helpful, it would be courteous for you to "Accept" it by ticking the check-mark next to his answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you give `Shell32` instead of `hShell32` in the `GetProcAddress` calls.

If you wonder why it fails with

> There is no overloaded version of 'GetProcAddress' that can be called with these arguments

you could ctrl-click on the first parameter, and the IDE will take you to the constant that the compiler finds for `Shell32`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to notes for anyone else thinking of using the above code, Delphi 2010 (maybe 2009?) has a unit called KnownFolders.pas containing all the other FOLDERID_ constants 
eg: 
FOLDERID_RoamingAppData: TGUID                 = '{3EB685DB-65F9-4CF6-A03A-E3EF65729F3D}';

Answer (score 2):

In Delphi 2010, all the SHGetKnownFile functions are defined in the unit "shlobj"
The FOLDERID constants are in KnownFolders